# Test if div exists on page and set focus to first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML that only appears when there is an error state:

```
<div class="validation-summary-errors text-danger">
  <span>Errors:</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Error, please refresh.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to set focus to that DIV which is far enough down the page that it cannot be seen when the user is at the top, so I tried this jQuery on the page:

```
  if ($('.validation-summary-errors').length) {
            $('.validation-summary-errors').first().focus();
  }
```

But it doesn't work, the focus is still at the default location (the top of the page) on page reload.

Comment: Maybe you just want to scroll down to that DIV, without setting focus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.focus()` does not apply to divs:

> The focus event is sent to an element when it gains focus. **This event
>   is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements,** **such as form
>   elements (, , etc.) and links ()**. In recent
>   browser versions, the event can be extended to include all element
>   types by explicitly setting the element's tabindex property. An
>   element can gain focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or
>   by mouse clicks on the element.

http://api.jquery.com/focus/

The best way to bring focus to a div or section is to scroll to it. You can do so with jQuery using `scrollTop`:

```
$('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $('yourElementHere').offset().top 
 }, 'slow');
```